# Solving for angular displacement

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The angular displacement $θ(t)$ of an object satisfies:

$\ddot{θ}=−2\sin(θ)$,  $θ(0) = \frac{π}{6} $ and $ \dot{θ}(0) = 0$

Find the angular speed $ |\dot{θ}| $ of the object when the angular displacement $θ=\frac{π}{12}$.

I'm trying to solve it with

$\ddot{θ}=\frac{d}{dθ}\left(\frac{\dot{θ}^2}{2}\right) $

I get as far as
$ \frac{\dot{θ}^2}{2} = 2\cos(θ) + C$  and have no idea how to solve for $θ$ from here. Am I missing something?

EDIT: Would it be possible to solve this question by regular integration? I don't think it is right? Since I would have to be integrating with respect to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\dot{θ}^2}{2} = 2\cos(θ) + C$$
Apply the given initial condition:
$$\frac{\dot{θ}^2(0)}{2} = 2\cos(\pi/6) + C$$
$$\implies C=-2\cos (\pi/6)=-\sqrt 3$$
The ODE becomes:$${\dot{θ}^2} = 4\cos(θ) -2\sqrt 3$$
Now you have that $\theta =\dfrac {\pi}{12}$ and $\cos(\pi/12)=\dfrac {1+\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2}$.
$${\dot{θ}^2} = {\sqrt 2(1+\sqrt 3)}-2\sqrt 3= 0.399...$$
$$|\dot \theta|=0.62$$

Comment: I think this is it! Would I need to solve the separable DE? Its al ready asking for speed, so I can just sub in $frac\{pi}{12}$ right?

Comment: Yes you're right you dont need to solve it @giddo244

Comment: Yes, I'm double checking now and that was the hahaha. https://imgur.com/a/J1OKLYD

Comment: OH yes, so I could sub in all the values as is as $t=0$ in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

No need to solve for $\theta$.

You know it's initial value.
Find out the value of the integration constant C, and then plug the required time into the obtained equation to get the answer.

Comment: Do you mean that I can sub in $\frac{pi}{6}$ and $0$ into the the equation to get $C = -sqrt(3)$? Then I plug in $\frac{pi}{12}$ to get the speed?

Comment: @giddo244 Isn't $\theta \dot{}( 0) =0$? Substitute this, get the value of C, and then plug in $\frac{\pi }{12}$ to get the final answer.